# Native coin MATIC has a Contract Address on the Polygon Network?

Tags: optimization, solidity, polygon, erc20, evm

I am currently developing a donation smart contract for the Polygon blockchain.
The donation contract should receive many types of coins like (MATIC, USDT, USDC, etc.).

I first made the donate function like the below:

```
function donate(address donor, address token, bool isNativeCoin, uint256 amount);
```

But later, I noticed that the Polygon network has MATIC address differently from other evm-based chains.

So I removed the `isNativeCoin` flag variable in the method params.

```
function donate(address donor, address token, uint256 amount);
```

But I don't know that is real MATIC address is and how Polygon is different from other chains.

Here is my research about Polygon MATIC and WMATIC address.

- MATIC

  https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010
  https://polygonscan.com/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010
- WMATIC

  https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x9c3c9283d3e44854697cd22d3faa240cfb032889#code
  https://polygonscan.com/address/0x0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270

*If I import 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010 as a token in my metamask wallet, it shows the same balance with Native MATIC balance. It's so interesting.*

Here is the full mockup code.

```
    address MATIC_TOKEN = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010;

    DonationInfo[] donations;
    
    function _safeTransferMatic(address to, uint256 amount) internal {
      (bool success, ) = to.call{value: amount}("");
      require(success, "MATIC_TRANSFER_FAILED");
    }
        
    function donate(address donor, address token, uint256 amount) {
      donations.push(DonationInfo(donor, token, amount);
    }
    
    function sendDonation(uint256 donateIndex) {
      if (donations[donateIndex].token == MATIC_TOKEN) {
        _safeTransferMatic(charityPartner, donations[donateIndex].amount);
      } else {
IERC20(donations[donateIndex].token).safeTransfer(charityPartner,donations[donateIndex].amount);
      }
    }
```

Is the above code correct or should I use `isNativeCoin` flag variable?

**Could you explain the Polygon MATIC address?**

Answer (score 0):

`0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010` is a *precompile* that supports *some* EIP-20 functions, such as `balanceOf(address)`, `name()`, `symbol()`, and `decimals()`. It does *not* support functions like `transfer(address, uint256)`, `approve(address, uint256)`, or `transferFrom(address, address, uint256)`.

Basically, it's a special address that isn't a contract that supports some, but not all EIP-20 functions.